# change the space between if() and { in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I type `if()` then `{` it looks like this
`if() {` with space and without the right curly brackets
I want when I type `if()` then `{` to look like this
without space and with the right curly brackets

```
if(){
   //code
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit -> White Space (tab) -> Control statements -> Blocks

There deselect option "before opening brace".

[image]
[image]

To also remove space before `else` deselect "after closing brace".

Comment: @sayedashraf That is another question (which I can't answer). Consider creating separate post about it.